# mapping JSON object in separate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to put all object names in HTML and I am using this function.

```
  function getExistingLinks() {
      $.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
        var names = data.map(function (i) {
        return i['link'].name
        });
        document.querySelector(".link-names").innerHTML = names;
      });
    }
```

html is very simple:

```
 <form id="addbookmark">
    <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="url">Url</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url" size="50" value="" /></p>
        <p class="link-names"></p>
    <p><input id="save" type="submit" value="Save Link" /></p>
  </form>
```

But in this situation all the names ale in one div .link-names,
I would prefer put each name in separate div .link-name
How can I do this?

Comment: Show us your **HTML**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about iterating over the names, and appending each?

```
var container = document.querySelector(".link-names");
names.forEach(function(name) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = name;
    container.appendChild(div);
    div.setAttribute('class', 'link-name');
});
```

Comment: well, with this i guess you end up having `$.map` and `forEach` ... two loops which is don't think is necessary.. is it ??

Answer (score 1):

use `$.each`

```
 $.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
   $.each(data,function (i,v) {
        var newDiv=$('<div />',{"class":"linkname",text:v.name});
        $('.link-names').append(newDiv);
        //or
         $('<div />',{"class":"linkname",text:v.name}).appendTo(".link-names");

    });

  });
```